# I don't understand uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Assume we have some series of functions defined for any $x\geq0$:

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3x+n}{x+n^{3}}$$

Let's assume uniform convergence. Meaning

$$\forall{\epsilon\geq0}, \exists N s.t. \forall{n \geq N}, \forall{p}, \forall{x\geq0}$$
$$ \lvert \frac{3x+(n+1)}{x+(n+1)^{3}} + \frac{3x+(n+2)}{x+(n+2)^{3}} + \cdots + \frac{3x+(n+p)}{x+(n+p)^{3}} \rvert \leq \epsilon $$

Let's pick a specific $n_0 \geq N$ and $p=1$:

$$ \lvert \frac{3x+(n_0)}{x+(n_0)^{3}} \rvert = \frac{3x+(n_0)}{x+(n_0)^{3}} \leq \epsilon $$

We know this is false, because $\lim_{x\to\infty}=3$ which obviously greater than many $\epsilon$.

*However*, this is the part I don't really understand... If instead of infinity, we approach some number $M\lt \infty$ then the series **is** uniformly convergent. Why?

What's to stop us from picking $M+1$ and continuing the series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just asserting that a series of functions is uniformly convergent is meaningless. What has a meaning is to assert that a series of functions converges uniformly (or not) on some given set. Your series does *not* converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$, but it *does* converge uniformly on any bounded subset of $[0,\infty)$. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Ah, so it really is *any* bounded subset. That really clears it up, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I have a small follow-up question: If we're asked to prove $S(x)$ is a continuous function for $x \geq 0$, it isn't, right? Because there needs to be an upper bound as well.

Comment: Yes, $S$ is continuous. Take $x_0\in[0,\infty)$. Then your series converges uniformly on $[0,x_0+1)$ and therefore the restriction of $S$ to that set is continuous. In particular, $S$ is continuous at $x_0$.